# Null Pointer Exception When Writing to ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I have this code to write a double number inside a txt file located in raw folder and another one to read the file and put all the double number inside the array. I use the array to do a average of the double number in the file.(The double is my ratingbar double)
The write is called in a button OnClickListener, after the read.

(Can someone edit this, I don't usually write in english, so i'm sure that it will have some mistakes, even in this quote probably)

Write:

```
private void writeMyArray(double rate){
        //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("arraymedia.txt", true)));
        //.println(rate);
        double ratex2 = rate * 2;
        int erate = (int)ratex2;
            try
            {
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("myarray.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
                outputStreamWriter.append(Integer.toString(erate));
                outputStreamWriter.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```

Read:

```
private void readMyArray(ArrayList<Double>array){

    String ret = "";


            try {
                InputStream inputStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myarray);

                if (inputStream != null) {
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    String receiveString = "";
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    int enc = 0;
                    while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                        array.set(enc, Double.parseDouble(bufferedReader.readLine()));
                        ++enc;
                    }
                    inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Average

```
private double media(ArrayList<Double>array)
{
    double total = 0;
    double media;
    int a = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<array.size(); i++)
    {
        total = total + array.get(i);
        a=i;
    }
    media = total / a;
    return media;
}
```

Error in the logcat

```
07-03 09:55:14.496  17307-17307/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.emilio.notification, PID: 17307
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.set(int, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.emilio.notification.MainActivity.readMyArray(MainActivity.java:210)
        at com.example.emilio.notification.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:45)
        at com.example.emilio.notification.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:111)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Button Click code

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ratingbar.setEnabled(false);
            rating = ratingbar.getRating();

           writeMyArray(rating);
            readMyArray(arraydays);
            button.setText(getText(R.string.obrigado) + "!" + media(arraydays));
            //button.setText(getText(R.string.obrigado)+"!");

            button.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

> UPTADE

when I change the array.set(), it gave me this error:

```
07-03 10:25:53.576  25334-25334/com.example.emilio.notification E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.emilio.notification, PID: 25334
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:481)
        at com.example.emilio.notification.MainActivity.readMyArray(MainActivity.java:210)
        at com.example.emilio.notification.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:45)
        at com.example.emilio.notification.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:111)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: What is problem with current code?

Comment: have you init the Array on readMyArray cause this the Error

Comment: It seems that `arrayDays` is not initialized.

Comment: Make sure you are calling `ArrayList<Double> arrayDays = new ArrayList<Double>();`

Comment: I haven't done that yet but my hardware is not that great, when the gradle finish i'll tell you if that worked or not.

Comment: Look at my answer, there are 2 problems with your code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your while loop

```
while(receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
```

This is fine, because it checks for the `null`.

But in your loop, you then get `bufferedReader.readLine()` again.

So this means, when the loop is on the last `string` that is not `null`.

The code is going to pick up the next `string` which is now equal to `null`.

```
while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);

    // The next line is the problem
    // bufferedReader.readline() is either null
    // or array is null

    // bufferedReader.readLine() is going to be set to null on the last run.
    array.set(enc, Double.parseDouble(bufferedReader.readLine()));

    ++enc;
}
```

I think you may be looking for this instead

```
array.set(enc, Double.parseDouble(receiveString));
```

or possibly this

```
string doubleToParse = bufferedReader.readLine();
if(doubleToParse != null) {
    array.set(enc, doubleToParse);
}
```

Note:
With the second answer, you will be taking two lines from the `bufferedReader` each time you pass through the loop.

The next problem you might be facing, is setting up your `ArrayList`.

Make sure you have already called

```
ArrayList<Double> arrayDays = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

And if you haven't populated the array already. You should be calling:

```
array.add(Double.parseDouble(doubleToParse));
```

On a final note, you must be certain that each string you are parsing actually contains a `Double`.

Or else you will face a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

```
try {
    Double d = Double.parseDouble(doubleToParse);
    array.add(d);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer. You should be using `array.add()`, because `array.set()` changes a `Double` which is already there. But it seems it is not already populated.

Comment: Thanks man! Now I have another problem, in my write code, I forgot to change the "myarray.txt" to the raw folder file, how can I cast the R.raw.myarray there?

Comment: Since that is a different question, I would open a new question. After searching and making sure there is no duplicate question of course :)

Comment: Here is a link to get you started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989239/updating-a-raw-resource-in-an-android-app :)

Comment: In the Write() method, would be more logical to this:  outputStreamWriter.append("\n" + Integer.toString(erate)); rather than this  outputStreamWriter.append(Integer.toString(erate)); right?

Comment: Yes, that would add the integer to a new line each time. `outputStreamWriter.append(Integer.toString(erate) + "\n")` :)

Answer (score 0):

Code seems to be fine try to replace

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myarray);
```

to

```
InputStream inputStream = MainActivity.this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myarray);
```

Should work for you.